# How to determine whether the template type is a basic type or a class

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have code something like this

```
template <typename T> void fun (T value)
{
    .....
    value.print ();  //Here if T is a class I want to call print (), 
                     //otherwise use printf
    .....
}
```

Now, to print the value, if T is a class, I want to call the print function of the object, but if T is a basic datatype, I just want to use printf.

So, how do I find if the Template type is a basic data type or a class?

Comment: What format string are you going to use for fundamental types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`std::is_class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) (and possibly `std::is_union`). The details depend on your definition of "basic type". See more on type support [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

But note that in C++ one usually overloads `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` for printing user defined types `T`. This way, you do not need to worry about whether the type passed to your function template is a class or not:

```
template <typename T> void fun (T value)
{
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 I can almost here the "how do I use that" train coming. Ditto on hmjd's answer. (and +1 to both).

Comment: @WhozCraig right, and the answer to that would be "you don't, you overload the output stream operator..."

Answer (score 3):

Recommend overloading [`operator<<(std::ostream&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for any type `T` instead of using `printf()`: how would you know what format specifier to use?

```
template <typename T> void fun (T value)
{
    .....
    std::cout << value <<  std::endl;
    .....
}
```

FWIW, [`std::is_class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class) exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have C++11 support, an alternative.

```
template<typename T>
class isClassT {
private:
    typedef char One;
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two;
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);
    template<typename C> static Two test(…);
public:
    enum { Yes = sizeof(isClassT<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1 };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};
```

A simple template for finding out if type is class type. More in [C++ Templates a Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842).

```
if (isClassT<T>::Yes) {
    std::cout << " Type is class " << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a printing helper function template/overload:

```
template <typename T>
void print(T const & t) { t.print(); }

template <typename U>
void print(U * p) { std::printf("%p", static_cast<void*>(p)); }
// we really an enable_if on is_object<U>::value here...

void print(char x) { std::printf("%c", x); }
void print(int x) { std::printf("%d", x); }

// etc. for all fundamental types
```

Then you can simply say `print(value);` in your code.