# How to get the type of a template, like template <typename T>, and to check if T is int or float or a class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

the problem is described briefly as below:

```
template <typename T>
void display(T data){
    if(is_int(T)) // how to check if T is int in this function is_int
        printf("<int> %d", data);
    if(is_float(T)) // how to check if T is float in this function is_float
        printf("<int> %f", data);
    if(is_class(T)) // how to check if T is class in this function is_class
        data.display();
}
```

Here suppose that T can be type of int or float or a class.

If I define some variables and want to display their values using the same function:

```
int a = 10:
float b = 2.7;
A_Class c;

display(a);
display(b);
display(c);
display(new int(3));
display(new float(1.899));
display(new float(1));
```

I know that in C++, there is one solution for checking int and float(just for the issue of printing), that is to use std::cout, as explained in this question([C++ templates - How to find whether the template type is a basic type or a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132123/c-templates-how-to-find-whether-the-template-type-is-a-basic-type-or-a-class)).

And using std::is_integral::value doesn't apply for the case like this:

```
display(new int(3));
display(new float(1.899));
display(new float(1));
```

because these variables are classes not the basic types. So for this situation, how we judge the type(int or float) of new int(), new float()?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to actually specialize the template on the type.  You can even create one to handle classes based on whether the class has a member function, like `display()`.

Comment: in your example you might just want to overload your function. I'm not sure what benefits you get out of templates here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To print the `int` and `float` values just provide overloads of `display()` that take arguments of those types, respectively. For objects that contain a member function named `display()`, you can use SFINAE to selectively enable the free function form of `display()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto display(T const& t) -> decltype(t.display(), void())
{
    std::cout << "display(T const& t)\n";
}

void display(int)
{
    std::cout << "display(int)\n";
}

void display(double)
{
    std::cout << "display(double)\n";
}

struct foo
{
    void display() const
    {
        std::cout << "foo::display\n";
    }
};

struct bar {};

int main()
{
    display(10);
    display(10.0);
    display(foo());
//    display(bar()); // doesn't compile
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bdb0e0e1f7353c3) of what happens when you call `display(bar());`

```
main.cpp:35:18: error: no matching function for call to 'display(bar)'

     display(bar()); // doesn't compile
...
main.cpp:5:49: error: 'const struct bar' has no member named 'display'
```

Comment: Could you clarify something in this answer?  I use trailing return syntax and decltype quite a bit, but your use of it in the template is unfamiliar to me.  Specifically this: "-> decltype(t.display(), void()) "   I would expect it to be "decltype(t.display())"  What is with the extra command and void ", void()"  How is that even syntactically valid and what does it mean, in rough terms?

Comment: @Joe `-> decltype(t.display())` alone would mean the return type of `display` is the same as that of `t.display()`. `, void()` is using the comma operator to add a second subexpression `void()`, so that the complete `decltype` expression yields a return type of `void`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988669/241631) where I've tried to explain it in detail (although that is a more complicated case than this one).

Comment: Even after 25 years of C++, my brain can still be made to explode.  Trailing return syntax as a trigger for SFINAE with the comma operator to achieve multiple objectives at once.   Brilliant.

Answer (score 5):

You provide the versions directly, check are provided by [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type
display(T data){
    printf("<int> %d", data);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value>::type
display(T data){
    printf("<int> %f", data);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value>::type
display(const T& data){ // you probably don't want to copy the argument
    data.display();
}
```

Comment: A better approach is to use overloads for `int`, `float` and then a template for the rest

Comment: @Mgetz: Well, not exactly as it is. If you specialize a template you must provide the same interface, that means settling for const reference in all cases (the penalty of passing `int` or `float` by reference seems to be a better alternative than having to pass random types by value). That being said, it is better to avoid template function specializations.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieving is using [numeric limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/). This is however, to check if it is an integer or a floating point number.

You could do the following:

```
#include<limits>
template <typename T>
void display(T data){
  if(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed) // how to check if T is int in this function is_int
     printf("<int> %d", data);
  else // how to check if T is float in this function is_float
     printf("<int> %f", data);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution! Simple, quick to implements, c++98 standard. Tkanks!