# Disable method override in template derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, boost, enable-if

Would it be possible to disable the `Foo()` override in the derived class (by means of `std::enable_if` or some boost magic), in case T is not of a certain type, without having to write a template specialization for `class Derived`?

Bonus points: could the override be disabled if T does not define a certain method?

Here is my SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo() override
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> testInt;
    std::cout << testInt.Foo() << std::endl;

    Derived<float> testFloat;
    std::cout << testFloat.Foo() << std::endl;//I would like this to print 'Base'
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for the wonderful solutions, but I wasn't able to adapt them to my real code. The following example should provide a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Object
{
public:
    void Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    }
};

class EmptyObject
{
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo() override
    {
        m_object.Test();
        return "Derived";
    }

private:
    T m_object;
};

int main()
{
    Derived<Object> testObject;
    std::cout << testObject.Foo() << std::endl;

    Derived<EmptyObject> testEmpty;
    std::cout << testEmpty.Foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In `C++11` you can mark the function `final` and it cannot be overwritten.

I don't know if you can do this with virtual functions, however.

Comment: That will not help. I do need to overwrite the method in some of the classes derived from Base (this was just a trivial example)

Comment: @user2899162 Of course, it can be done with virtual functions. **And only with them.**

Comment: Ah @Constructor, wasn't sure if I was mixing up my syntax. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating two functions that `Derived::Foo` can delegate to conditionally based on whether `T = float`. One would contain the real `Derived::Foo` implementation, while the other would call `Base::Foo`.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo() override
    {
        return do_Foo(std::is_same<T, float>{});
    }

private:
    std::string do_Foo(std::false_type)
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
    std::string do_Foo(std::true_type)
    {
        return Base::Foo();
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55edfdabfb64e6f4)

---

It seems what you actually want to do is call the `Derived<T>::Foo()` implementation only if `T` defines a certain member function, otherwise `Base::Foo()` should be called. This can be done using expression SFINAE.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::string Foo() override
    {
        return do_Foo(true);
    }
private:
    template<typename U = T>
    auto do_Foo(bool)
        -> decltype(std::declval<U>().test(), void(), std::string())
    {
        return "Derived";
    }
    std::string do_Foo(int)
    {
        return Base::Foo();
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/642ded793aecd61b)

In the code above, if the type `T` does not define a member function named `test()`, the `do_Foo(bool)` member function template will not be viable. On the other hand, if `T::test()` does exist, then `do_Foo(bool)` will be selected because the boolean value being passed to `do_Foo` by `Foo` makes it a better match as compared to `do_Foo(int)`.

A detailed explanation of what's going on within the `decltype` expression in the trailing return type can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988669/241631).

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but, sadly, it doesn't work in my real code, because do_Foo needs to call a method on an object of type `T`, so I need to try something else...

Comment: @MihaiTodor You could forward the object to `do_Foo()`. If you show what the signature of your `Foo()` function looks like, I can update the answer.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I don't see the problem. Call `m_object.Test();` in `std::string do_Foo(std::false_type)` and don't call it in `std::string do_Foo(std::true_type)`. That solves the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, darn it! I forgot that VS2012 does not support uniform initialization. Thanks a lot! It worked.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I've updated the answer. When I first answered, I missed the part where your real requirement is to call `Derived:Foo()` only if `T` defines a particular member function. Edit: The updated stuff may not work on VS since it doesn't support expression SFINAE yet.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed awesome! Unfortunately, I'll have to make my code work on VS2012, which spits out "error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template" on your last example. Anyhow, in decltype, why is `void()` required? As far as I can understand, decltype will return the type of the last expression in the comma separated list.

Comment: @MihaiTodor Check the answer I linked to at the end. The explanation was long enough that I didn't want to copy-paste it all over again.

Comment: Ah, how cute :) Who would have thought that someone might overload the comma operator?... I think I should be able to make my code work now. Thank you very much for all your help help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of template specialize the class, you may template specialize the method directly: (https://ideone.com/gYwt5r)

```
template<> std::string Derived<float>::Foo() { return Base::Foo(); }
```

And I only see template specialization of a class to disable future override depending of `T` by adding `final` to the virtual method.

Comment: But, this requires me to make the method a template too, right?

Comment: No, the method is not template. see the link for complete code.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry for the silly comment and thank you for your help. It does work, but for my real code, I found @Praetorian's suggestion more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to restrict a certain type at **compile time**, you can use `std::enable_if` together with `std::is_same` :

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value, std::string>::type 
virtual Foo() override
{
    return "Derived";
}
```

Or you can easily redirect the call to the `Base` method if the template type is not the type you are looking for, still with `std::is_same` :

```
virtual std::string Foo() override
{
    return std::is_same<T, float>::value ? Base::Foo() : "Derived";
}
```

---

As for the **Bonus**, you can get the trait from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/257382#257382), adapted here with `decltype`, for a method `bar()` :

```
template <typename T>
class has_bar
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test(decltype(&C::bar) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

The limitation is that you can't put constraints on the arguments or return types.

```
virtual std::string Foo() override
{
    return has_bar<T>::value ? "Derived" : Base::Foo() ;
}
```

**Note:**

You could also use `has_bar` together with `enable_if` as in my first example, to disable it a compile time.

Comment: This looks promising, but I think I'm doing something wrong with enable_if: https://ideone.com/MTWBu8

Comment: No you are not : it does not **compile** because enable_if removed the method (see me post, it is in my first line), thats the point of enable_if (use the other methods if you still want it to compile when used with the unwanted type)

Comment: Oh, right. I see now. Sadly, I don't think I will be able to get the redirection trick to work in my case. This example should be closer to the real situation: https://ideone.com/C6g6tx

Comment: This is related to the "Bonus" right ? you can use the trait has_bar and change is to has_test exactly the same way. Does that make sense ? Do you want an edit ?

Comment: If you could spare some time, I'd love to see a working example. For now, I think I'll be able to achieve my goals with @Praetorian's solution. Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an intermediate class to your hierarchy:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Intermediate : public Base
{
    // common operations with m_object

protected: // not private!
    T m_object;
};

template <typename T, typename = bool>
class Derived : public Intermediate<T> {};

template <typename T>
class Derived<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().Test(), void(), true)>
    : public Intermediate<T>
{
public:
    virtual std::string Foo() override
    {
        this->m_object.Test(); // this-> is necessary here!
        return "Derived";
    }
};
```

The full example compiles successfully with both [*clang 3.4*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23f34da3ba124d0c) and [*g++ 4.8.2*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed8cbae03ea83c50).

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I was trying to avoid this, due to the fact that my modifications lie somewhere deep in legacy code, and I might break something... Also, VS2012 doesn't seem to like the expression SFINAE trick, which is a shame, so I ended up using `std::is_same<T, MyObject>` in order to detect the type for which to call `Test()`, which is something I don't like to do in generic code, but I don't want to mess with the `sizeof` method detection trick right now...