# Function overloading with templates - applying enable_if only when alternative function exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, enable-if

I managed to overload insertion operator for `std::ostream` based on rank of object. 
I would like to extend below example.

When `A_new.h` is included, it includes `A.h`... in this case I am checking rank of object and I am calling `f_alterantive` or `f_old`. Works as expected :)

The problem appears when `A.h` is included directly, then there only one instance of `f()` - `f_old`.

If there is only one instance of `f()` included directly through `A.h`, then it should be default for all objects... (not only for `rank > 1`, but also for all rest)
and below condition has no sense.

```
typename std::enable_if <(std::rank<T>::value > 1), int>::type = 0 >
```

I know that I need to specify condition which checks if another `f()` exists:
something like:

```
//goal:    typename std::enable_if <((f_alternative_exist == false) || (std::rank<T>::value > 1 && f_alternative_exist == true) ), int>::type = 0 >
```

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988669/9854242), but I am still not sure how to do it with `std::enable_if`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {
};
    //--- alternative header A_new.h
    //#include A.h
    template< class T,
             typename std::enable_if<(std::rank<T>::value == 1), int>::type = 0 >
    void f(std::ostream& os, const T& value)
    //f_alternative 
    {
        os << "alternative function\n";
        os << "rank == 1" << std::endl;
    }
    //----

    //---- old header A.h
    template < class T,
               typename std::enable_if <(std::rank<T>::value > 1), int>::type = 0 >
    //goal:    typename std::enable_if <((f_alternative_exist == false) || (std::rank<T>::value > 1 && f_alternative_exist == true) ), int>::type = 0 >
    void f(std::ostream& os, const T& value)
    //f_old
    {
        os << "old function\n";
        os << "rank > 1" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& foo)
    {
        f<T>(os, foo);
        return os;
    }
    //-----

int main()
{
    Foo foo1[5];
    Foo foo2[5][5];

    std::cout << foo1; 
    std::cout << foo2;

    return 0;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f7ef7bda1805a36

Could you tell me how can I specify `std::enable_if` to work also when `f()` is not overloaded and when it should run for all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible `f_alternative_exist` is the following

```
template <typename T>
std::false_type f_alternative_exist_f (std::ostream &, T const &, long);

template <typename T>
auto f_alternative_exist_f (std::ostream & os, T const & t, int)
   -> decltype( f(os, t), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using f_alternative_exist
   = decltype(f_alternative_exist_f(std::declval<std::ostream &>(),
                                    std::declval<T>(), 0));

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool f_alternative_exist_v
   = f_alternative_exist<T>::value;
```

The old version become

```
template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<(std::rank<T>::value > 1)
                        || (false == f_alternative_exist_v<T>), int> = 0 >
void f (std::ostream & os, T const &)
 {
   os << "old function\n";
   os << "rank > 1" << std::endl;
 }
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>

class Foo
 { };

template <typename T>
std::false_type f_alternative_exist_f (std::ostream &, T const &, long);

template <typename T>
auto f_alternative_exist_f (std::ostream & os, T const & t, int)
   -> decltype( f(os, t), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using f_alternative_exist
   = decltype(f_alternative_exist_f(std::declval<std::ostream &>(),
                                    std::declval<T>(), 0));

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool f_alternative_exist_v
   = f_alternative_exist<T>::value;

#if 0 // enable/disable
template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<std::rank<T>::value == 1, int> = 0 >
void f (std::ostream & os, T const &)
 {
   os << "alternative function\n";
   os << "rank == 1" << std::endl;
 }
#endif

template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<(std::rank<T>::value > 1)
                        || (false == f_alternative_exist_v<T>), int> = 0 >
void f (std::ostream & os, T const &)
 {
   os << "old function\n";
   os << "rank > 1" << std::endl;
 }

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& foo)
 {
   f<T>(os, foo);
   return os;
 }

int main ()
 {
   Foo foo1[5];
   Foo foo2[5][5];

   std::cout << foo1; 
   std::cout << foo2;
 }
```